# Read mail and add values from mail body to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, client-object-model, csom, ews

I have a requirement where I have d to read mail (in a prescribed format) from a folder in outlook inbox, separate the values and create a new item in SharePoint list and then move the mail to another folder in the inbox, so as to know that they are added to SharePoint list.

## Folders in Outlook be like:

[image]

## Mail format be like:

[image]

The code should be CSOM and be installed on just one client machine (maybe the admin person would run it).

Note: Subjects is a multi-choice field.

Comment: Why the programming? Where does the OOTB Email Enabled Library fail for you? And why are you asking and immedialty answering your own question?

Comment: This is when Email enabled list and Site mailbox is not allowed at client's end

Comment: Ah yes.. that's what I call Flintstone projects... We bought a car, but we're not allowed to use petrol so we're now walking inside the car like Fred and Barney...  Yabadabadoo! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2s13X66BFd8

Comment: Exactly sir, I had proposed petrol but they preferred to walk and hence, this workaround. You can up vote the answer, it worked like a charm for my Flintstones project :D

Comment: But why did you ask and immediatly answered your own question?

Comment: You can do that, it's not just QnA, it's also knowledge sharing. CLICK ON THIS LINK:  [its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can acheive this by writing a CSOM code, making it an executable file and running it via Windows Scheduler on a particular machine. So, create a Console Application in Visual Studio.

### Program.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using EWS = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ReadMail
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckEmailFolderForContents();
        }

        private static void CheckEmailFolderForContents()
        {
            ExchangeService ews = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
            {
                Credentials = new WebCredentials(
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exchangeUsername"],   //username
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exchangePassword"])   //password
            };

            ews.AutodiscoverUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["exchangeUsername"] + "@abc.com");     //the mail ID whose inbox has to be accessed
            FindFoldersResults folderSearchResults = ews.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new FolderView(int.MaxValue));
            EWS.Folder exchangeExchangeAPIArchivedFolder = folderSearchResults.Folders.ToList().Find(
                f => f.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolder"], StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
            //Set the number of items we can deal with at anyone time.
            ItemView itemView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);
            foreach (EWS.Folder folder in folderSearchResults.Folders)
            {
                if (folder.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootFolder"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    EWS.Folder boundFolder = EWS.Folder.Bind(ews, folder.Id);
                    SearchFilter unreadSearchFilter =
                        new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
                            LogicalOperator.And
                            , new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(
                                EmailMessageSchema.Subject,
                                "RootFolder",
                                ContainmentMode.Substring,
                                ComparisonMode.IgnoreCase)
                                );
                    //Find the unread messages in the email folder.
                    FindItemsResults<Item> unreadMessages = boundFolder.FindItems(unreadSearchFilter, itemView);
                    if (unreadMessages.TotalCount > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (EmailMessage message in unreadMessages)
                        {
                            message.Load();
                            PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.Body);
                            propSet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
                            var email = EmailMessage.Bind(ews, message.Id, propSet);
                            message.Load(propSet);
                            String mailBody = message.Body;

                            UpdateListItem(mailBody);

                            foreach (EWS.Folder folder1 in folderSearchResults.Folders)
                            {
                                if (folder1.DisplayName.Equals(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArchiveFolder"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    var fid = folder1.Id;
                                    message.Move(fid);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private static void UpdateListItem(string Body)
        {
            string siteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("StudentDetails");
                ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                String[] values = Body.Split(';');         //split the body into key value pair and store it in an array
                for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    String[] valueset = values[i].Split(':');   //split the key and value from the pair and add it in an array
                    if (valueset[0] == "Subjects")
                    {
                        String[] SelectedChoiceVaue = valueset[1].Split(',');   //split the subjects separated by ,
                        List<string> Topics = new List<string>();
                        for (var j = 0; j < SelectedChoiceVaue.Length; j++) Topics.Add(SelectedChoiceVaue[j].Trim());
                        oListItem["Subjects"] = Topics;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oListItem[valueset[0]] = valueset[1];
                    }
                }
                oListItem.Update();
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### The app.config code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
<appSettings>
  <add key="exchangeUsername" value="sherlock.holmes"/>
  <add key="exchangePassword" value="IreneAdler#123"/>
  <add key="RootFolder" value="RootFolder"/>
  <add key="ArchiveFolder" value="ArchivedFolder"/>
  <add key="URL" value="<your site url>"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```